# Maven build giving "[WARNING] The POM for sqljdbc:sqljdbc:jar:4 is missing, no dependency information available" from jenkins CL server

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins to perform build and test to my maven project. but while build process i am getting this issue "[WARNING] The POM for sqljdbc:sqljdbc:jar:4 is missing, no dependency information available", how to resolve it...for jenkins CL server

Comment: add your pom.xml at least the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

sqljdbc.jar is not available in maven central. It is possible that someone in your organization has uploaded it manually in your artifactory or nexus. The correct way is to use artifactory or nexus user interface.  This will auto add pom.xml which is used to download transitive dependency.

I think its a warning since maven assumes that transitive dependency problem will probably be caught as compilation failure.